# When "lock time" was added to Bitcoin?

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions, bitcoin-core-development

Since when lock time exist in Bitcoin transactions?

Comment: You may be thinking of the CLTV opcode (which allows putting requirements on the nLockTime of spending transactions), which was added in BIP65 (activated in 2013).

Comment: There was no mistake :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the very beginning. Transactions have had the `nLockTime` field since Bitcoin 0.1.0.

Comment: Though interestingly, it worked differently until a soft fork. It used to be signed, and was changed to unsigned.